# Refreshing base adapter with Vector of elements (Android)

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have Vector of elements that i set into `BaseAdapter` subclass and this adapter works with this elements

I need to refresh my list, so i set new vector to my adapter class and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` method but it doesent work.

how can i fix it

UPDT:

Here is code of my refreshing method

```
public void updateGroups(Page page) {
        this.page = page;
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.groups_list);
        SelectGroupsListAdapter adapter =(SelectGroupsListAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
        adapter.setGroups(page.getItems());
        listView.invalidate();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }
```

Comment: what doesn't work? what error do you get? where is you code?

Comment: I have no error, my ListView just doesn't refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that adapter.setGroups(page.getItems()); add the objects to the adapter, and you are in a ListActivity, so, did you try this:

((SelectGroupsListAdapter )getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

or

((SelectGroupsListAdapter )listAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

if your setGroups(page.getItems()) set a new vector be sure to add explicitly each vector element:

the adapter inner method: setGroups(...)

```
public void setGroups(List<?> newData){
  for(Object o : newData){
    add(o);
  }
}
```

Comment: adapter.setGroups(page.getItems()); sets new vector as adapters data source.